# Typesetting Metrical Phonology

Tags: linguistics, pst-asr

I am trying to achieve graphics similar to that in this image:
[image]

Currently, I'm using pst-asr, which seems like a good tool for the job, however, after scouring the documentation, I'm still not sure how to get past the basic parser. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: We have some `pst-asr` questions on the site: [Autosegmental Representation with pst-asr](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176645) and also [Autosegmental Representation in tikz-qtree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240361). Depending on what you want to do, the `forest` package might also be able to do what you need. Remember that `pst-asr` requires compilation with `latex+dvips` or `xelatex` (not `pdflatex`).  Perhaps if you post a minimal document of what you've tried the few of us here who have used `pst-asr` could help.

Comment: Thank you! That second thread contained exactly what I needed. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it could be of help.  Your question will be closed as a duplicate.